# Is there any way to use Web Share Api for other browsers than Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I actually implemented Web Share API in Mobile web app, which is working fine in Chrome, since it is featured developed by Google for Chrome. But I want the same functionality to be work on few other browsers such as **FF and Opera**.

Is there any way to do so, or else it's mandatory to add Custom pop up for those browser whichever is not supporting Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for WebShare API is spreading - it is now supported in Safari on both Desktop in Mobile as of early 2019. You can see the list of supported browsers here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-share

You can easily feature detect if the client's browser supports it by doing `if (navigator.share)`. Straightforward example here: https://alligator.io/js/web-share-api/

But yes, if it's not supported you will need to create an alternative non-native pop up with the share options you want to offer the user. (This is what I just implemented at the news site I work at).